# C#: Textbox to multiple strings

Tags: c#, string

Just a C# beginner here that just build his first application and now wants to make some changes to make it more ideal.

Today I got three textboxes where the users type in year, month and project number.
When they click GO the application opens the respective folder: L:\2019\01\20190133

I would like to make it simpler, one textbox that gets divided into three strings (year, month, PO-number).

Any ideas? Sorry for the bad format of this post, feel free to correct/shame me :)

Current code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int tbyear;
        int tbmonth;
        int tbpnr;

        tbyear = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        tbmonth = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        tbpnr = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

        string tby = textBox1.Text;
        string tbm = textBox2.Text;
        string tbnr = textBox3.Text;
        string path = Path.Combine(tby, tbm);
        string pathnr = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text + textBox3.Text;
        
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"L:\" + path + "\\" + pathnr);
```

Comment: When a user types in the combined information into the single text box, how do you expect the user to format the input? What characters are allowed in the input?

Comment: @gunr2171: The input would be 20190133 in the case above.

Comment: So the first 4 characters are the year. Characters 5 and 6 are the month. The rest of the characters are the PO number. Do you know about [substring](https://www.dotnetperls.com/substring)?

Comment: @gunr2171: That looks like exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a very simple example of text extraction, use [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1).

```
string textFromInputControl = "20190133";
        
string year = textFromInputControl.Substring(0, 4); // start at index 0, 4 chars long
string month = textFromInputControl.Substring(4, 2); // start at index 4, 2 chars long
string poNumber = textFromInputControl.Substring(6); // start at index 6, all remaining chars
        
Console.WriteLine(year);     // "2019"
Console.WriteLine(month);    // "01"
Console.WriteLine(poNumber); // "33"
```

There are, of course, more complex ways of doing text extraction, like Regex. Use other tools when they are more appropriate.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks for next-level response time and good advice. Learned a lot that I probably should have fund by myself through Google..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure that entering all three items into one textbox is simpler from a user's perspective, but if you want to do that here's one way:

This assumes that the entries are separated in some way (we'll go with a space character).

```cs
var parts = textbox.Text.Split(' ');
var pathToOpen = $@"L:\{parts[0]}\{parts[1]}\{parts[2]}";
```

The above code splits the contents of the textbox by its `' '` delimiter, then formats them into a path in the format you provided.

Edit: going by the comments, you don't want to have a delimiter. In the case that your first two parts of the path are of fixed length, you can use the `Substring` method to extract them:

```cs
var year = textbox.Text.Substring(0, 4);
var month = textbox.Text.Substring(4, 2);
var rest = textbox.Text.Substring(6);
```

Comment: It's not separated by anything. I prefer the separate textboxes but unfortunately the merge is a user request :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's fine as it is. If you have 3 differents inputs in 3 differents textboxes it's well designed.
Imagine that one day you make a change and you don't want to join these types for generate your path: *year\month\projectNumber*.
This would implies to change UI + Code. If you keep your input in only 1 text box, the changes only affect to code.

Comment: A very legitimate reason to have one text box is when you are scanning a barcode, and the barcode contains all the information in one string.